# documentation on setup test_suite argument

Tags: python, packaging

**Feature in question**

I'm looking for documentation on a feature that let's you specify the test cases for a python packages and run them using setup. For example if my setup.py file was:

```
from setuptools setup
setup(
    name='foo',
    version='1.0',
    py_modules=['foo'],
    test_suite='testsuite.test_all.suite',
)
```

I could then run the package's test cases with the following command:

```
python setup.py test
```

**Where I have looked**

- The [PEP Index](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/) - there are many PEPs related to packaging I couldn't find mention of the test_suite feature in them.
- [Distributing Python Modules](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/) documentation mention it either.

**What I want to know**

- what does test_suite expect? from what I can tell it expects a test suite and you can refer to one directly or a callable that returns one.
- Some projects specify their test suite in their setup.py like Flask some don't like Django. What is the benefit of specifying this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for [distribute](http://pythonhosted.org/distribute/index.html) has a very good section called [Build package and run a unittest suite](http://pythonhosted.org/distribute/setuptools.html#test-build-package-and-run-a-unittest-suite) that explains the use of test_suite pretty well.

**what does test_suite expect?**

> To use this command, your project’s tests must be wrapped in a
>   unittest test suite by either a function, a TestCase class or method,
>   or a module or package containing TestCase classes. If the named suite
>   is a module, and the module has an additional_tests() function, it is
>   called and the result (which must be a unittest.TestSuite) is added to
>   the tests to be run. If the named suite is a package, any submodules
>   and subpackages are recursively added to the overall test suite.

**What is the benefit of specifying this?**

By specifying the testing mechanism in your setup.py applications can automatically detect where the test suites are and run them.